# Creating Tabs with the name selected from select input function in shiny

Tags: mysql, drop-down-menu, shiny, tabs

I want to form tabs dynamically in my app i.e when i will select choices from my drop down menu and as soon as i select one option a tab with the same name should appear.The options which select input is showing is coming from my database.To made the scenario clear i am attaching sample app which is showing tabs dynamically and i later on i will attach my code 
Here us sample app:

```
 library(shiny)
 ui <- (fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Demonstration of renderUI in shiny - Dymanically creating      the tabs based on user inputs"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # Numeric input to enter the number of tabs needed
      numericInput("n", 'Enter the number of tabs needed', 1)

    ),
    mainPanel(
     uiOutput('tabs')
   )
 )
   ))


server <- (function(input,output){

  output$tabs = renderUI({
Tabs <- lapply(paste("tab no.", 1:input$n, sep=" "), tabPanel)
do.call(tabsetPanel, Tabs)
  })
 })
 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here tabs are increasing according to numbers incremented and decremented, i have drop down menu which will show tuples of my database table which are as shown here

```
| name                 |
+----------------------+
| aaa                  |     
| kart                 |
```

and here is my code with error:

```
    library("shiny")
   library("shinydashboard")
   library("pool")
  library("DBI")
  pool <- dbPool(drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),dbname = "demo",host =    "db.cr7dht.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com",username = "kak",password =    "1278", port = 3306)
  mychoices = dbGetQuery(pool,"select available_scenario from sc;")
  ui <- (fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Demonstration of renderUI in shiny - Dymanically creating    the       tabs based on user inputs"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
       selectInput('n', "available scenarios", choices = mychoices,    multiple      = TRUE),
        verbatimTextOutput("selected")

   ),
   mainPanel(
      uiOutput('tabs')
   )
  )
))
 server <- (function(input,output,session){
  output$tabs = renderUI({
    observe({
    updateSelectInput(
    session, "n", choices = mychoices
  )
})
Tabs <- lapply(paste("tab name", 1:input$choices, sep=" "), tabPanel)
do.call(tabsetPanel, Tabs)

  })
})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: In your own code `input$choices` is a *character* vector. So `1:input$choices` will throw an error. Try with `1:length(input$choices)` instead. Also [insertTab](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.1.0/insertTab.html) might be useful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you don't want a tabpannel if `n` is `NULL` so I added the `is.null` check. Secondly remove the `1:` when  you are generating the tabs. the paste function will automatically convert your `inpu$n` to multiple characters string. No need to insert a range.

In  addition, you don't need to put the `updateSelectInput` in your `renderUI` function.

**Working example**

```
mychoices = 1:10
ui <- (fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Demonstration of renderUI in shiny - Dymanically creating    the       tabs based on user inputs"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput('n', "available scenarios", choices =    mychoices,    multiple      = TRUE),
      verbatimTextOutput("selected")),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput('tabs')
    )
  )
))

server <- (function(input,output,session){
  output$tabs = renderUI({
    if(!is.null(input$n)){
      Tabs <- lapply(paste("tab name", input$n, sep=" "), tabPanel)
      do.call(tabsetPanel, Tabs)}

  })
})
```